# Backbone polling server for changes - then re-render?

Tags: json, backbone.js, fetch, backbone-views, polling

I'm trying to use Backbone to pull daily events from a JSON API, and to periodically check for changes in the JSON - and to re-render those changes. Also - the app will be long running, so I'll have a periodic check for the date - so that when the date changes, so does the URL of the collection and the collection is re-fetched and re-rendered.

However, when I re-fetch the data (whether it has been modified or is new data entirely) --- it isn't firing any change events on the model or collection.

I could paste my code - but it may save time to just ask simply:

What would the process be for polling the server for new/modified data, then  adding/removing/updating the models on the view? I don't need to do any *writing* to the server, just pulling the content - and polling ever 30 seconds for changes.

Would that be a sync? fetch?

I've searched the web for methods on this - but with continuous changes to the Backbone API - I haven't been able to find a viable solution thus far.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all : Backbone as such has no method to "periodically" fetch data from an API.You will need to handle that using JavaScript

Answering each of your questions :

Q. What would the process be for polling the server for new/modified data, then adding/removing/updating the models on the view? 
A. As mentioned above you need to handle that through JS, doing something like

```
setInterval(function(){
//Make an API call to get data
},30000);
```

Q. I don't need to do any writing to the server, just pulling the content - and polling ever 30 seconds for changes.Would that be a sync? fetch?

A. Id say the backbone fetch method would be appropriate one.

Make API call every 30 seconds :

```
setInterval(function(){
  collection.fetch();
},30000);
```

Listen to the fetch complete and re-render your view

```
collection.on('reset',this.render(),this);
```

Hope this answers your query in a nutshell.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Actually - what you're suggesting is what I've been trying. 

I have the `collection.on('reset', function, this)` set on my Collection view - but it doesn't get run when I call fetch on the collection.

http://pastebin.com/4R9gMZEw -- the collection view

Comment: did you try adding a success function to your collection.fetch, just to check if that works ? something like collection.fetch({success:function(resp){ //do smething },error:function(resp,status){ //check what went wrong }});

Comment: I think you would need to pass `{reset:true}` as an option to fetch in your call to `setInterval` or listen for the `sync` event on the collection instead. `collection.on('sync',this.render,this)`..note it should be `this.render`, not `this.render()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, every `Backbone` component can `listenTo` and `trigger` events. There are a lot of built-in events but nothing prevents you from implementing your own.

Here is a purely *event driven* implementation solution to your problem. This has the advantage to scale easily, if anything else needs to happen every 30 seconds in your application, it's just a matter of registering a callback to the right event.

```
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo( Backbone, 'tick:30secs', this.fetch, this );
    return this;
  },
  // Example date-dependent url.
  url : function() {
    var date = new Date(); 
    return 'http://server.com/api/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getDay();
  }
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  // Assuming you store your template in the HTML page.
  template: _.template($('#view-template')),
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset change add', this.render, this );
    setInterval(function() { Backbone.trigger('tick:30secs'); }, 30000);
    return this;
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.collection.toJSON) );
    return this;
  }
});

// Start everything up.
var collection = new Data(),
    view = new View({ collection: collection });
$('body').append( view.el );
collection.fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

[backbone-poller](https://github.com/uzikilon/backbone-poller) seems like a nice implementation for backbone.